# Environment.getRootDirectory() returns null on listFiles() function

Tags: java, android, local-storage, android-permissions, permission-denied

My `ArrayList pdfs` returns empty Array list on pass passing `Environment.getDataDirectory()`  , `Environment.getRootDirectory()` or the deprecated `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to it.

```
static ArrayList pdfs=new ArrayList<File>();

public static void Search_Dir(File dir){
        String pdfPattern = ".pdf";
        File FileList[] =dir.listFiles();
        if(FileList != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < FileList.length; i++){
                if(FileList[i].isDirectory()) {
                    Search_Dir(FileList[i]);
                }
                else {
                    if(FileList[i].getName().endsWith(pdfPattern)){
                        pdfs.add(FileList[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("NULLHERE","OOPS NULL HERE");
        }
```

What is the way out please?
Also I have included Read and Write `Permissions` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Did you check in App management settign whether READ/WRITE permission is allowed. Also you can try adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in Manifest.

Comment: I checked in App management settings, and storage permission is allowed. I will add the line in the ```Manifest``` file and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MediaStore was what I later used and it gave me what I wanted. Too much heck with the `listFiles()` function.